# Javascript convert image to PNG

Tags: javascript, c++, type-conversion

After seing alot of examples here, and try to use them they work in some degree, but it doesn't true convert the image.

The image as the extension now png and open as such, but if I go into properties it stills says :

[image: Example of my problem]

on C# and HTML the image shows without any problem, but I'm using the language c++ and it won't show on the QPushButton

This is an example of the code that I'm using on the javascript to convert the image:

```
// Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element
function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

return canvas;
}

function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
return image;
}
```

So the image is saved throught base64 to png opens as such on many programs but on the one that I'm trying to do it wont.

How to I properly convert an image to png ?! Since this method isn't working

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Humm I think I did, but well here it goes and I will edit it for it. I have tryed to convert the image to PNG, but it didn't complete convert it, as it shows on the image. The extension of the file is PNG but the contents it says its an JPEG and that on QPushButton will not work since the convertion did not work well, and I use the same code as above to do it